# Is there a way to make the raycast node use individual ray directions for every vertex, so that the projection looks like my annotated lines?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

Quick question, is there a way to make the raycast node use individual ray directions for every vertex, so that the projection looks like my annotated lines? What's wrong with my node setup?

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more what you are trying to achieve? what is your end goal? yes, it is possible by using e.g. the position node....

Comment: @Chris thank you for the tip, i've worked it out!

Comment: Glad you made it!

Comment: @Valentin Heinz: can you share the full working solution? Thanks!

Comment: @igmar Well I honestly don't know if any of this info is still up to date, since geo nodes have been reworked like a dozen times over the past 2 years. I dont have that specific file anymore, but I still have the file I was working on that I needed this for. I made a video on it here: https://youtu.be/tvAZCfXsWAs and the .blend file can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D_0uClj5_l4RDwVLrkNwVfmNEsFn5jWy

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wanted to know how Valentin Heinz managed to raycast omnidirectionally from a point origin instead of parallel lines, here his node-setup in his .blend:

[image: The raycast Ray Direction have as input a vector-math node that subtract the world-position to the object-info(location) of the Ray-origin object]