# Raycast of multiple rays from single point source in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is it possible to cast multiple rays from a single point source in the raycast node? The idea is to pass a "list" of Ray Directions, and to obtain a "list" of Hit Positions. This is to avoid the use of multiple Raycast nodes when the number of desired rays is very high.
The problem seems similar to this [old question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249901/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-raycast-node-use-individual-ray-directions-for-every), but unfortunately the author didn't share his solution.

The following image should explain what I need:
[image]
Currently, the two red spots are obtained joining two patches, whose locations is calculated using two raycast node:
[image]

The question is if it is possible to have multiple raycasts with only one raycast node.

Thank you

Comment: Sure, you could associate any number of points with a single point (say, by capturing index to an instanced mesh) so you could shoot any number of rays from a single point, using a single raycast node.  But I'd have a lot of trouble saying how you could do this *usefully* without knowing what your actual goal was with it.

Comment: Using a Repeat Zone in B4.0 you could store named attributes using an iterator to dynamically create a string, e.g. `ray0`, `ray1`, `ray2` etc.

Comment: you could use a duplicate elements, but my question to you is how are you going to pass a list? what is the list gonna be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a setup that simulates Suzanne being shot with a paintball shotgun:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome.. I need to study this solution to fully understand it. Is the geometry node modifier applied to Suzanne or to another object?

Comment: @igmar to Suzanne, though the raycasts are run on newly spawned points, and the raycast starting position is set to the empty visible on the screenshot (the end of the shotgun barrel).